# Laravel authentication in nativescript-vue app, anyone has done it?

Tags: javascript, android, laravel, vue.js, nativescript

I'm fairly new to nativescript-vue dev and I'd like to set authentication for my native app, I have been thinking about using firebase auth but I'd rather go the laravel route (if it's a good choice at all).

How I think I'd handle this is to send a post request to my backend (which is a laravel app) into my custom auth controller, then in the success callback I'd change isLogged in the vuex store to true or false, since I'm suing also vuex-persistedstate to persist some data into my localStorage (actually it's Application Settings in natviescript afaik).

Is my way of doing this okk? has anyone done it?

Comment: Your backend code is completely your choice, in {N} or any mobile app anything from app to server is just a Http call. And Yes, you may store auth tokens in local storage (application settings).

Answer (score 1):

I was using a Laravel API before, but decided to switch back to Firebase, I think it’s a better choice for mobile.

But if you want to use Laravel, take a look at Laravel Passport  (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport).

You can use the Password Grant (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#password-grant-tokens) to generate a token from your mobile application, by creating a login endpoint that will generate the token for you.